# Load CSV from R matrix into D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I have a 2 column matrix I've saved out of R that looks like :

```
    ,y
     4.93707840,-2.17356434
     4.41122212,-1.96256698
     4.21076739,-1.75156962
     4.06441510,-1.54057226
```

The code I'm using is :

```
    var data = d3.text("2013.csv", function(unparsedData)
    {
    var dataset = d3.csv.parseRows(unparsedData);

    // Code here

    })
```

Only the second column is imported. There is a header row which contains ,y which I really need to skip or replace.

Any ideas?

I tried this :

```
    var dataset

    d3.csv("2013.csv", function (error, dataset) {
    console.log(dataset)
```

But still only the 2nd column is imported.

Comment: What returns null? Are you running a webserver? Also note that you can use `d3.csv` to load and parse CSV directly.

Comment: Lars, I edited the question.  The first column is ignored - I think due to ,y i.e. blank column 1.  If I debug I can see column 2 values. Everywhere I see CSV I see it being used with column headers. I am running lamp.

Comment: Could you add a header for the first column?

Comment: I'll give it a try from R.  I was hoping there was a skip header parameter in D3?

Comment: You could use `d3.csv.parseRows` to parse the rows without the header.

Comment: I amended the R code with :

write.table(series1,file="/var/www/2013.csv",sep=",", col.names = c('X','Y'), row.names = F)

This gives me headers in quotes but D3 still only imports the 2nd column.

Comment: I sorted - reloaded dev tools in firefox and see both columns.   JS is horrible.